# Loop and write to a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to loop through a XML file, and parse out the elements that I need.  I can print to the console window just fine, but the results are too large, and fill the entire console before before it ends.  So, I am trying to dump everything to a CSV file.  Now, it seems like I get only one single character per row in the CSV when the script finishes.  My code must be close, but obviously something is wrong.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse('C:\\path\\Recon.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

with open('C:\\path\\data.csv', 'w') as f:

    for neighbor in root.iter('inputColumn'):
        print(neighbor.attrib)
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(neighbor.attrib)
```

I am using 3.6.3!

Just posting the final version of my code here....

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse('C:\\path\\Recon.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

with open('C:\\path\\data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for neighbor in root.iter('inputColumn'):
        print(neighbor.attrib)
        writer.writerow(neighbor.attrib)
```

This is so, so, so simple.  After working with Python for a few years, and (basically) hating it, I am really starting to love it now!!

Comment: Try to move `write = csv.writer(f)` above the `for neighbor` loop.

Comment: You need to create a csv writer only once, right after you open the file. You're creating many writes which may clobber each other.

Comment: Do `writer.writerow` not "writerows".

Comment: Yeap, i had to move the write line before the for loop and drop that 's' and now it works.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to reflect comments above for ease of future reference.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse('C:\\path\\Recon.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

with open('C:\\path\\data.csv', 'w') as f:

    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for neighbor in root.iter('inputColumn'):
        print(neighbor.attrib)
        writer.writerow(neighbor.attrib)
```